# Node equations for Thevenin voltage

Tags: thevenin, nodal-analysis, norton

I have the following circuit as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I am interested only on finding the \$V_{th}\$ and not the Norton current.
I choose to work with node analysis because I find it easier. In this problem I took two nodes \$V_{0}\$ and \$V_{1}\$ as shown :

[image]

I have two equations :

\$\frac{V_{0}-5}{200} +\frac{V_{2}}{5} + \frac{V_{0}-V_{1}}{-j50} = 0\$

\$\frac{V_{1}-V_{0}}{-j50} +88I_{\phi} + \frac{V_{1}}{10}=0 \$

where :
\$I_{\phi} = \frac{V_{0}-5}{200} \$ and \$ V_{2} = \frac{V_{1}}{10} \$

My question is just a confirmation : Is my node equations correct ?

Plus: the result must be : \$V_{2} = -66 + 88i\$ but when I try to solve it I find something different.So I am guessing that something is wrong with my equations. Can someone confirm or comment for my mistake ?

Comment: The v2/5 in the first equation doesn't make sense to me. That value isn't a current.

Comment: @periblepsis so I have to exclude it ?

Comment: No. There may be a current. You just can't claim it is v2/5.

Comment: @periblepsis if I substitute V2 with V1/10 it will result to V1/50.So the there is a current.

Comment: V2 is v1. There is no difference. Assuming the bottom node as ground reference.

Comment: @periblepsis therefore I have to take only V0 into account.?and v0=V2/5.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nodes

Let's get one thing straight. When doing circuit analysis:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQtkT1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Spend some time to make sure you are comfortable with all three:

1. **Top**: This is wrong because there's only ***one*** node on top of the schematic. Not six of them. Just one. Sure, in practice there are wires and these wires carry a current. But for purposes of analysis there is only one node at the top of this schematic. Do not ever consider it differently.
2. **Middle**: This shows you how to view #1, above. Just one node. That's all.
3. **Bottom**: In this case I've inserted \$0\:\text{V}\$ voltage sources in between each of the `so-called` nodes in #1. Doing this does allow you to number the nodes, distinctly. However, doing so introduces a new unknown current for each of these added \$0\:\text{V}\$ voltage sources. It greatly complicates the analysis. But you can do it this way and get the same results you'd get from #2 above, but taking the long way around the barn to get there.

   The ***only*** good reason for inserting \$0\:\text{V}\$ voltage sources like this is to get a handle on the current that might take place on a specific wire you are interested in considering. You are allowed to break up a node like this, if for example you wanted to build a circuit in two pieces and there was a wire between them and you wanted to know the current on it. But keep in mind that this adds another variable and complicates analysis. You need a good reason to do this.

### Nodal (KCL) Analysis Preparation

Let's get another thing straight. While mesh analysis works fine without setting a ground node -- all it is doing is working out the mesh currents which do not need a reference point -- nodal analysis pretty much **requires** that you assign a ground node so that the node voltages you work out in the analysis have a common reference point. This avoids a `circular argument`, so to speak. So you need to assign a ground before starting nodal analysis.

There's another far less important reason for assigning a ground node: it ***simplifies*** the equations because some of the terms will have *zero* in the numerator and therefore can be discarded from analysis. This reduces complexity.

So here is what you do to prepare the schematic for nodal analysis:

[image]

Note that the **a** is gone. We don't need it. You are allowed to keep it in mind, if you want: that it is just another name for \$v_2\$. But there's no point keeping it around. So dump it. It only gets in the way.

### Nodal Solution

With the above, we can now develop the KCL equations:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{X_{C_1}}+i_x&=\frac{v_s}{R_1}+\frac{v_2}{X_{C_1}}
\\\\
\frac{v_2}{R_2}+\frac{v_2}{X_{C_1}}+88\cdot\frac{v_s-v_1}{R_1}&=\frac{v_1}{X_{C_1}}
\end{align*}$$

There's one more equation needed based upon the fact that \$v_1\$ is determined by \$v_2\$ (\$v_1\$ is dependent and \$v_2\$ is independent.)

$$\begin{align*}
v_1=\frac15 v_2
\end{align*}$$

These can now be solved together:

```
from sympy import *                        # required once per session
from sympy.solvers import solve            # required once per session
var( 'r1 r2 c1 vs v1 v2 ix')               # declare variables
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/c1 + ix, vs/r1 + v2/c1 )     # nodal for v1
eq2 = Eq( v2/r2 + v2/c1 + 88*(vs-v1)/r1, v1/c1 )  # nodal for v2
eq3 = Eq( v1, v2/5 )                              # v1 depends on v2
results = solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ v1, v2, ix ] )
for i in results: i, results[i].subs( { r1:200, r2:10, c1:-50*I, vs:5 } )
(v1, -66/5 + 88*I/5)
(v2, -66 + 88*I)
(ix, -1317/1000 - 143*I/125)
```

*(I'm using freely available [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) for this -- they run on a variety of environments and use the [Python](https://www.python.org/) language.)*

Note that your expected result occurs for \$v_2\$, above. Also note that \$v_1\$ is one-fifth of \$v_2\$.

Now, technically, we don't really care about \$i_x\$. We get a result for it, but it's not important what the value is here. What is important is that we recognize this unknown and make it part of the system we solve. Even if we don't actually need its value. Just like we don't need to know \$v_1\$, either. All you really want is \$v_2\$. But you still have to solve other unknowns to get there.

### Summary

It's good practice to stop using constants and start using variable names (such as \$R_1\$ and \$X_{C_1}\$) for parts in the schematic. You may already know their values, but it's just good practice to get into doing it this way.

Part of the reason is that this allows you to separate out the effects of one part from another, when you get your results. For example, you know that \$v_2=-66+88\cdot I\$. But did you know that:

$$v_2=\frac{v_s}{\frac15-\frac{1}{88}\cdot\left(\frac{R_1}{R_2}+\left(1-\frac15\right)\cdot\frac{ R_1}{X_{C_1}}\right)}$$

In solving this symbolically, you have a chance at observing a few things about the roles played by the various devices and constants used in the circuit. Note the ratios of \$R_1\$ to both \$R_2\$ and \$X_{C_1}\$? Might these suggest further questions or thoughts in your mind?

Comment: how you express ix ? in terms of variables.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Any time you have a voltage source, you also have a current through it. I told you earlier that you don't know what that current is and that you cannot just call the current `v2/5`, for example. You don't get to do that. Partly, because it's just wrong -- and in the wrong units, too. Instead, I recognized that it is really an unknown value, you need to assign that unknown a variable name, and so I just made that fact explicit, as such. That means I don't know what it is, but I can use it in the equations and solve for it, too. (Not that I care what it is.) The process works.

Comment: understood.thank you for your crystal clear answer as always